# Rails 4 with Devise - nested form fields in user registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, nested-attributes

I'm trying to build a user registration process in rails using devise.

I have models for User and OrganisationRequest.

The associations are:

User:

```
has_one :organisation_request, through: :profile 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :organisation_request
```

OrganisationRequest:

```
belongs_to :profile
# no explicit association on user
```

In my users/registrations controller, I have:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  def new
    resource = build_resource({})  
    resource.build_organisation_request
  end

  def create
    super do |user|
      if user.persisted?
        User::CompleteRegistrationService.call(user: user)
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, 
      :organisation_request_attributes => [:organisation_id ] ) }
  end

  # TODO not sure we still need this
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    finish_signup_path(resource)

  end


end
```

In my registrations new form, I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<%= render partial: 'organisation_request/fields', locals: { f: f } %>
```

The partial has:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :organisation_request do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :organisation_id, collection: @all_organisations << ['other', 100000] %>
                </div>
<% end %>
```

When that didn't work, I tried moving the form element directly into the user new registration form as follows:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :organisation_request do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :organisation_id, collection: @all_organisations << ['other', 100000] %>
                </div>
<% end %>
```

In each case, when I save all this and try it, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `build_organisation_request' for #<User:0x007ff583259858>
```

Can anyone see what's gone wrong?

Comment: `build_resource({})` just builds you a user object. So since it doesn't have and `id` when you call `build_organisation_request` it results in an error

Comment: Try building the profile, then have the profile build the organisation request. e.g.  ------ resource.build_profile   and then resource.profile.build_organisation_request  -- This isn't an issue of having an id, but more an issue of building the parent record first.